# How to have windows forms control catch drag enter instead of embedded WPF canvas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, winforms

This is a pretty basic setup. I have a System.Windows.Forms Panel that holds an ElementHost control that holds a System.Windows.Controls Canvas. The user begins a drag operation and the drag enter event is fired from the Canvas control, but what I really want is for the canvas to ignore the drag enter and for the event to be caught by the parent System.Windows.Forms.Panel that holds the canvas. How can I do this?

Comment: This is a simple hang-up, D+D can only work when the drop target is visible to the mouse cursor.  It is not, your panel is covered by the ElementHost.  And it in turn is covered by the Canvas, the reason its D+D events are hidden.  Not completely covering the panel would be a workaround of sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to this, is that you cannot do that. If you mix Win32, WPF, or DirectX technologies on top of each other, then the one on top takes precedence and it is a black hole to the other technologies. The limitation you are experiencing is called **Airspace** and if you search around you will find many articles discussing airspace restrictions and mixing WPF/Winforms/DirectX content. Please see the following link:

[Technology Regions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

There may be methods that would help to provide a workaround for what you are trying to accomplish. For example, handling the input in WPF and then passing it explicitly back to your program in some other manner. Some quick googling shows:

[Mitigating Airspace Issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2013/02/26/mitigating-airspace-issues-in-wpf-applications.aspx)

[WPF and Win32 Interoption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx)